# Remove special characters from a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```
def paragraph(para,special1):    
    for i in special1:
        word1=para.replace(i,"")    
    return word1

p="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sem odio..."
sp1=",_!@*%#$."

print(paragraph(p,sp1))
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Aliquam sem odio
```

Expected Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Aliquam sem odio
```

I want remove all the special characters in special1 string from para. But ',' is not getting removed.

Comment: `word1` gets assigned _new_ string in each iteration. Change to `para=para.replace(...); return para`

Comment: You can also make a set: `s = set(special1)` and then filter based on it to avoid searching the same string over and over: `return ''.join(c for c in para if c not in s)`

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you

my_string=''.join(ch for ch in my_string if ch.isspace() or ch.isalnum())

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, string

def paragraph(para,special1): 
    clean_string = re.sub(rf"[{string.punctuation}]", "", para)  
    return clean_string

p="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sem odio...  ,_!@*%#$."
sp1=u",_!@*%#$."

print(paragraph(p,sp1))
```

or

```
def paragraph(para,special1):    
    for i in special1:
        para=para.replace(i,"")    
    return para

p="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sem odio..."
sp1=",_!@*%#$."

print(paragraph(p,sp1))
```